# Document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code in the - `$(document).ready(function()`{ - that shuffles stuff around, the code is fired when the page is loaded but what I want to do is add a button so this function runs every time I press the button, how could I achieve this, thanks??

Comment: What have you tried? Just put the code in the click event handler of the the button.

Answer (score 3):

```
function shuffleStuffAround() {
    // truffle shuffle
}

$(function($) { // DOM ready
    shuffleStuffAround();

    $("#some-button").click(function() {
        shuffleStuffAround();
        return false; // you probably want this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save you "shuffle stuff around" code as a function and call it from other parts of your codebase.

```
var foo = function() {
  // code that shuffles stuff around
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  foo();
  // other stuff
});

$('#mybutton').click(foo);
//or
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  foo();
  // other stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple refactor the code that you run on the ready function into its own function and call that in your button's click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    codeToRun();
    $('.button').click(function(){codeToRun()});
});

function codeToRun(){
    // do work
}
```